# How to return to inital agent of a Jenkinx matrix after a stage executed on another agent?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible in a Matrix-cell of a Jenkins declarative pipeline to execute a later stage on the pipeline's 'initial/main' agent, after a previous stage of the same cell has been executed on another agent (identified by label)?

To put this into context, I want to build native-binaries for different platforms in a Jenkins declarative pipeline using a matrix stage where each cell is responsible to

1. collect the native's sources for that platform
2. build the native-binaries from the sources for that platform
3. collect the just build native-binaries and distribute them to the platform specific artefacts

Step two has to be performed on special agents, which are prepared to build the binaries for a particular platform and are identified by their label. Step one and three has to be performed on the initial agent, the pipeline's 'main' agent where the sources are checkout from SCM. In the end the native-binaries are bundled together and distributed from the pipeline's inital/main agent. To transfer of sources and binaries `stash/unstash` is used.

A exemplary, simplified pseudo pipeline would look like:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'basic' }
    // Declarative SCM checkout configured in the mutli-branch pipeline job-config
    stages {
        stage('Build binaries') {
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'PLATFORM'
                        values 'linux', 'windows'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage("Collect sources") {
                        steps {
                            <Collect native's sources for ${PLATFORM}> in "${WORKSPACE}/native.sources.${PLATFORM}"
                            dir("native.sources.${PLATFORM}") {
                                stash "sources.${PLATFORM}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Build binaries') {
                        options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
                        agent { label "natives-${PLATFORM}" }
                        steps {
                            unstash "sources.${PLATFORM}"
                            <Build native binaries from unstashed sources into 'libs' folder >
                            dir('libs') {
                                stash "binaries.${PLATFORM}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Collect and distribute binaries') {
                        agent {
                            <initial/pipeline-agent>
                        }
                        steps {
                            dir("libs.${PLATFORM}") {
                                unstash "binaries.${PLATFORM}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Bundle and distribute') {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But the question is, how do I tell Jenkins to execute the third stage of the matrix on the initial/pipeline agent again?
If I simply don't specify an agent for the third-stage the execution is:

1. Stage on Pipeline-Agent
2. Stage on Native-Build-Agent
3. Stage on Native-Build-Agent

but I want:

1. Stage on Pipeline-Agent
2. Stage on Native-Build-Agent
3. Stage on Pipeline-Agent

In the syntax-reference I didn't find a agent parameter like `agent { <initial/pipeline-agent> }`:

- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent
- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#matrix-cell-directives

The agent section describes a boolean option `reuseNode`, but it is only "`valid for docker and dockerfile`".

The only workaround I found so far, was to define a second matrix and move the execution of the third stage to that. This works as expect and the stage is executed on the pipeline-agent, but has the drawback that the matrix-stage has to be specified twice as well as its when-conditions.

**Appendix**

The problem probably also exists, when using per stage agents in an ordinary linear pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with by myself is to wrap the stage that should run on another agent in a `script` block that contains a `node` (and thus starts another agent), which contains the desired steps of the stage.

```
stage('Things to do on another agent') {
  steps {
    script {
      node('${PLATFORM}') {
        stage('Do things on another agent') {
         <The steps to do >
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After the node has completed the execution returns to the initial agent.
Of course the workspace on the other agent is not set up by default like the initial agent (e.g. no repository is checked out) and has to be set up explicitly.

This solution applied to my example above would look like the following

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'basic' }
    // Declarative SCM checkout configured in the mutli-branch pipeline job-config
    stages {
        stage('Build binaries') {
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'PLATFORM'
                        values 'linux', 'windows'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage("Collect sources") {
                        steps {
                            <Collect native's sources for ${PLATFORM}> in "${WORKSPACE}/native.sources.${PLATFORM}"
                            dir("native.sources.${PLATFORM}") {
                                stash "sources.${PLATFORM}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Build binaries') {
                        steps {
                            script {
                                node("natives-${PLATFORM}") {
                                    stage('Build binariess') {
                                        unstash "sources.${PLATFORM}"
                                        <Build native binaries from unstashed sources into 'libs' folder >
                                        dir('libs') {
                                            stash "binaries.${PLATFORM}"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Collect and distribute binaries') {
                        steps {
                            dir("libs.${PLATFORM}") {
                                unstash "binaries.${PLATFORM}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Bundle and distribute') {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```